# Can't connect to PostgreSQL database with symfony

Tags: database, postgresql, symfony1

I'm new to PostgreSQL and this is my first symfony project with PostgreSQL. When I try to run `insert-sql` in symfony, it tells me my database, `salon`, doesn't exist. But it does exist, as you can see below.

```
ason@ve:~/salon$ ./symfony doc:insert-sql
>> doctrine  creating tables


  PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "SALON" does not exist  


jason@ve:~/salon$ sudo -u postgres createdb salon;
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "salon" already exists
```

It seems that any symfony command I run will tell me that `salon` doesn't exist (I've tried others). For this reason, my guess is that this is a symfony problem as opposed to a PostgreSQL or PHP problem.

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=SALON
      username: salon
      password: foobar123
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Update: I can connect to my PostgreSQL with a plain, non-symfony PHP script, so the problem must lie with symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy, do I feel dumb. If I use `dbname=salon` instead of `dbname=SALON`, it works.

Comment: Well, database names are case sensitive.